# How can I retrieve a component instance from an ng-template?

Tags: angular

I have a directive that needs access to a component instance in order to function correctly.

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[helloDirective]'
})
export class HelloDirective implements AfterContentInit {

  @ContentChild(HelloComponent) helloComponent: HelloComponent;

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    if (this.helloComponent) {
      console.log(`Hello ${this.helloComponent.name}!`);
    } else {
      console.error('helloComponent is undefined')
    }
  }
}
```

If I use `HelloComponent` as content inside a wrapper with `helloDirective` on it, everything works as expected. The directive has access to the component instance:

```html
<div helloDirective>
  <hello [name]="'Bob'"></hello>
</div>
```

The console prints `Hello Bob!` with no problems.

However, if I use a container that references a template as content:

```html
<div helloDirective>
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="tpl"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #tpl>
  <hello [name]="'Suzy'"></hello>
</ng-template>
```

The console prints `helloComponent is undefined` since the content is now contained in a template.

The documentation for [ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild) says:

> Does not retrieve elements or directives that are in other
> components' templates, since a component's template is always a black
> box to its ancestors.

I would like to reuse a template view instead of copying and pasting the code for the view everywhere.

How can I attach the view of `#tpl` as content so `HelloDirective` can find a component instance of `HelloComponent`?

[StackBlitz example of the problem here!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hjgyg4?file=src/app/app.component.html)